# Promises and Cordova File API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a very basic messaging platform using MVC 5 for the backend WebAPI and using Cordova to help store messaging offline. I'm currently trying to save the messages in a Json file and recall them from the Json file if the API request fails.

Everything is working great except I'm running into an Async issue with my data being returned. I've tried to use javascript promises to help fix this issue, but I'm getting and error saying I can't use a .when on an undefined.

I'm assuming that I'm misunderstanding promises; Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong, or provide another method to handle the async issues?

Initial Inbox Function calls the API when the API errors out or isn't found then I'm getting data from offline files:

```
function Inbox(dataService, $q) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.messages =
        dataService.getMessages().then(function(data) {
                vm.UnreadCount = getUnreadCount(data.data);
                vm.messages = data.data;
            }, function(err) {

                getOfflineMessages($q).then(function(data) {
                    vm.UnreadCount = getUnreadCount(data);
                    vm.messages = data;
                });
            }
        );


}



function getOfflineMessages($q) {
    var data;

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFSRead, fail);

        function gotFSRead(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile("messages.txt", null, gotFileEntryRead, fail);

        }

        function gotFileEntryRead(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(gotFileRead, fail);

        }

        function gotFileRead(file) {
            ReadDataRead(file);

        }

        function ReadDataRead(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                data = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);



            }
            reader.readAsText(file);


        }

        function fail(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        }

        debugger;
        return $q.when(data);


}
```

Comment: you need to pass `$q` parameter when calling the `getOfflineMessages()` inside the `Inbox()` call. e.g `getOfflineMessages($q).then....` Since you have not passed the `$q` it is passed as `null` and hence the error `undefined` at `return $q.when(data)`.

Comment: Great find, I've updated my code to reflect the changes, I'm still running into async issues however; I've added a debugger to show where there needs to be a pause for the other functions to run correctly, I was hoping the .when(data) would wait for data to be populated but I think that I've miss understood its usage.